# How to add filter for wordpress plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters

I have a really newbie question, but I'm really new to WordPress development. In the plugin that I'm using is using this filter.

```
if ( true === apply_filters( 'some_custom_filter', false ) ) {
   return $something;
}
```

Now I'd like to `add_filter` so it will return `true` how do I achieve that?

This is what I'm trying but doesn't work it always return `false`

```
public function setup_filters() {
    add_filter( 'some_custom_filter', array( $this, 'filter_suppress_the_content' ), 10, 3 );
}

public function filter_suppress_the_content() {
    return true;
}
```

This is the class.

```
private static $instance;
private static $wpcom_related_posts;

public static function get_instance() {
    if( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
        self::$instance = new Klazz;
        self::$instance->setup_filters();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

public function setup_filters() {
    add_filter( 'some_custom_filter', array( $this, 'filter_suppress_the_content' ), 10, 1 );
}

public function filter_suppress_the_content( $false) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost close.

```
add_filter( 'some_custom_filter', array( $this, 'filter_suppress_the_content' ), 10, 3 );
// the above line states that, the method `filter_suppress_the_content` should have three arguments, where you have used nothing.


public function filter_suppress_the_content() {
    return true;
}
// comparing your code, this method should have one argument
```

The solution:

```
public function setup_filters() {
  add_filter( 'some_custom_filter', array( $this, 'filter_suppress_the_content' ), 10, 1 );
}
public function filter_suppress_the_content( $false ){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code it's still returning `false`

Comment: Exactly where did you called the `setup_filters` method ? please include the full code. Note: `apply_filters` should be called before `add_filter`.

Comment: I've included the fullcode and `apply_filters` is being called in the plugin.

Comment: That's it I have to call it before `apply_filters` thanks!

Comment: Awesome :) Note: WP has some quick functions to make things easier. Such as `__return_false`, `__return_true`, `__return_empty_array` etc. So for doing true/false type return, you can just use them quickly. ex: `add_filter( 'some_custom_filter', '__return_false');`